# How can I put all graphs for different sample size `n=10, 100, 1000, 2000` in the same plot?

Tags: plotting

For a sample size `n=1000`, I plot the following graph based the code

```
n = 1000; 
m = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[n], n]]; 
{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[m]; 
h = evec[[All, 1]]; 
imin = Ordering[eval, 1][[1]]; 
lambda2minlambda1 = Sort[eval][[2]] - Sort[eval][[1]]; 
tn = 1/(4*lambda2minlambda1);
```

```
*plot the function H1 (t)

Plot[Abs[h[[imin]]]*Exp[-2*eval[[imin]]*t]/Sqrt[Sum[h[[i]]^2*Exp[-4*eval[[i]]*t], {i, 1, n}]], 
{t, 0, 10*tn}, 
 GridLines -> {{tn}, {}}, GridLinesStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

**Question: How can I put all graphs for different sample size `n=10, 100, 1000, 2000` in the same plot and add a red line `y=1` in it?**

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Have you tried the `Show` command ?

Comment: @Syed What do you mean? I just first time use Mathematica.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74575227/how-can-i-put-all-graphs-for-different-sample-size-n-10-100-1000-2000-in-th